# ¿por qué no puedo usar los comandos de gatsby en la terminal de vs code?

Tags: vscode, gatsby

Por ejemplo uso `gatsby -v` y me sale un error

```
gatsby : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\gatsby.ps1 porque    
la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para obtener más información,        
consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.      
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ gatsby -v
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

o coloco `gatsby develop` y me sale este error

```
gatsby : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\gatsby.ps1 porque 
la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para obtener más información,        
consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.      
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ gatsby develop
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

y pues la verdad necesito solucionar esto porque por ejemplo, cada vez que elimino un archivo innecesario o hago algun cambio, tengo que hacer el gatsby develop desde la terminal de la pc y eso toma mucho tiempo, tan solo para hacer cambios, porque me sale un pop up de gatsby que dice failed to compile explicando el error y eso.

por ultimo, encontre esto

> If you weren’t able to install the Gatsby command line interface
> globally, you can start your development server using the following
> command instead: `npm run develop`

entonces el hecho de que no me funcione el command line de gatsby en vs code, es por no haberlo instalado globally?...pero me acuerdo haber usado el

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Comment: Cuando dices que te falla en la terminal de VS Code, ¿te refieres a que si abres una terminal por separado si te funciona? De se así, ¿ambas terminales son de Powershell? Parece ser una restricción de Powershell, ¿has intentado seguir las recomendaciones del link que se adjunta en el mensaje de error?

Comment: uy bien si eso era, es que no lei bien ese mensaje, gracias, la proxima voy a tener en cuenta leer esos mensajes, gracias que bien, ....oye otra pregunta, para borrar los proyectos de gatsby simplemente le doy delete y ya no?, o los debo eliminar del command prompt?

Comment: a traves del command prompt?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con borrar los proyectos del command prompt? El comando `delete` al que te refieres es de Powershell ¿no?

Comment: @ricardo-dlc, hola, si es que como veo que para instalar un proyecto en gatsby se instala solamente por la terminal, entonces no se, me pregunto si para eliminar un proyecto se tiene que usar algun protocolo especifico a traves de la terminal, yo los he estado eliminando normalmente dandole delete al folder y ya

Comment: Pues no realmente, solo basta con eliminar los archivos como mejor te acomodes, ya sea por línea de comandos o desde el explorador de archivos.

Comment: ah rebien, gracias , si es que tenia esa duda...saludos!